# Change only the year on the output of the "date"-command

Tags: shell, scripting, date

`date` for example displays `Fri Apr 17 20:16:01 IST 2015`

Now I want to change only the year so `date` should display `Fri Apr 17 20:16:01 IST 2016` in this example.

How to add 1 year to the output of `date` using Linux commands?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to let `date` create the standard date formatting you could do:

```
$ date -d "$( date -d "Fri Apr 17 20:16:01 IST 2015" "+2016-%m-%d %T" )"
```

But you can also use just one date instance and use the appropriate time format specifiers, as in:

```
date -d "Fri Apr 17 20:16:01 IST 2015" "+%a %b %e %T %Z 2016"
```

Or - since your date format has the year at the end - do just string processing on the reference date, e.g. using `awk`, as in:

```
date -d "Fri Apr 17 20:16:01 IST 2015" | awk '$NF=2016'
```

If the year is not fixed but should be the next year:

```
date -d "Fri Apr 17 20:16:01 IST 2015" | awk '++$NF'
```

If your date is already in a string `date_string` that could be:

```
awk '$NF=2016' <<< "${date_string}"
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU date accepts a number of relative dates that you can supply with the `-d` flag.

```
$ date -d '+1year'
Sun Apr 17 09:15:14 PDT 2016
```

See [Relative items in date strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#SEC127) for details.